# Property 'close' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

in this part of the code im doing a post request, and the `finally` part of my code isnt working.

i tried to find what could be wrong, based in another code that i did, but cant find where did i miss, maybe because this code is more well divided and long, since its a group project, if any other part of the code may be necessary, please tell me so i can provide it. (the .post()(createCarController) is in another file, and im using express and mongodb, if thats a doubt)

if this code that i provided is not enought or unrelevant for the question, please add a comment so i can (add more/remove part) of the code

```
export const createCarController = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    let connMongo: MongoClient | null = null;
    
    try {

        const conn = await getMongoConnection();
        const db = conn.db();
        const carCollection = db.collection("cars");

        const carData = req.body;
        const newId = new ObjectId();
        
        const newIdString = newId.toString();

        const car = new Carro(
            newIdString,
            carData.nome,
            carData.preco,
            carData.cor,
            carData.fabricante,
            carData.categoria,
            carData.ano_lancamento,
            carData.assentos,
            carData.potencia,
            carData.aro,
            carData.versao,
            carData.peso,
            carData.abastecimento
        );
        
        try{    
                (validations that i pressumed werent needed for helping solving my problem)
            }
        }catch (err){
            res.status(400).json({message: (err as Error).message});
            return;
        }

        const carDocument = {
            ...car,
        };

        const result = await carCollection.insertOne(carDocument);

        const insertedId = result.insertedId;

        const insertedCar = await carCollection.findOne({ _id: insertedId });

        res.status(201).json({
            message: "Carro criado com sucesso", carro: insertedCar
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({message: (err as Error).message});
        return;
    }
    finally {
        connMongo?.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: You have 2 conn variables

Comment: i edited the first to connMongo and stills dont work

Comment: Ideally your example code should be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Any values or types you use that are not native to TypeScript should be declared.  If your question actually depends on a third party library (e.g., mongodb, express, etc) then you should tag it as such, so that the right people can see it and respond.  Otherwise you should try to remove such references. You can use [the TypeScript Playground](//www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to test whether you've got a [mre] (but please post the result as *plaintext* here, not only as a link)

Comment: `connMongo` is never assigned a value other than `null`

Answer (score 0):

I belive if you change your

```
const conn = await getMongoConnection();
```

to

```
conn = await getMongoConnection();
```

It should work as expected.

You are redeclaring a **conn** constant in the **try** block, therefore when it reaches the **finally** block, it cannot recognize it because it's a different block.

Just declare it once in top (which you already did), and everything should work as intended.